# Incomplete Downloads of PDF Files using 'wget' and 'requests' Packages in Python

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, python-requests

I am currently encountering an issue with downloading PDF files from PDF URLs stored in a pandas dataframe in Python. While 97% of the files download successfully using the 'wget' and 'requests' packages, 2% of the files download but fail to load properly in Adobe Acrobat or in a browser. Additionally, the size of these files is reduced from their original size to 0-7KB. To ensure the complete and accurate download of all PDF files, I am seeking advice on alternative approaches or packages to consider.

For example, when attempting to download a PDF file from the following URL 'https://www.example.pdf', which is originally 71.5 KB in size, the file downloads but is unable to load, and its size is reduced to 7KB. Can anyone offer suggestions on how to resolve this issue or recommend a better approach to downloading these PDF files?

Comment: What happens if you download them in a browser?

Comment: Have you looked at what's inside the failing files? I'd bet it's an error message instead of the content you're looking for.

Comment: For start you can inspect response headers. Compare headers for incomplete PDF (7KB) with headers for full PDF.